# In Android C2DM what is Role (sender) account email?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have searched through net about C2DM and the process of registration of android device to the C2DM is very confusing. In the code below :-

```
Intent rI = new Intent ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
rI.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
rI.putExtra("sender", "myapp@example.com");
this.startService(rI);
```

What is "app", "sender" and "myapp@example.com"? I tried to signup for the Android C2DM but I couldn't understand what is the Role account email. 
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have shown, the only thing you need to replace is `myapp@example.com`.

First you need to create a Google GMail account, e.g., yourappname@gmail.com

Then you need to go to the [Sign Up for Android Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html) page. Fill in all of the details on the sign up page and provide your GMail account as the 'Role (sender)'. Then in your code, replace `myapp@example.com` with the GMail address you've created.

EDIT: In response to your comment/question.

`rI` is an `Intent` and you are putting 'extra' data into that `Intent` which is passed to the Google C2DM registration service.

When you put data into an `Intent`, it has to have a key name so the receiver of the `Intent` is able to extract it using `getStringExtra(keyName)` (for example). The keys 'app' and 'sender' are reserved for C2DM registration and MUST be used as they are in that code otherwise the C2DM registration process will fail.

Comment: can u explain me what is meaning of putting the specific string "app" and "sender" in the code.

Comment: yaa thanks for such a nice explanation.( i know that... sorry for asking such silly question about "app" and "sender"). And what about getting whitelisted as you are telling that I can send as soon as I signup. But when I run my application the broadcast receiver doesn't pick any response from C2DM.

Comment: I found it took 20-30 minutes to receive an email telling me the account had been white-listed and that email told me it could take up to 24 hours before I was able to use the C2DM service.